# Serving videos in Rails API with paper clip

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, video, paperclip, rails-api

I am building a blog like API in Rails, where I need to take videos from the android and ios app store them in a pg DB on heroku and serve them to the client in a way they would be able to play it on the client device.

Can anyone guide me how to do that with paperclip? please.
At moment this is what my CURL request `GET => /posts/1` trows back.

```
 /system/posts/videos/000/000/001/original/VID_20160123_201801.mp4?1453620267
```

But the android app is not able to play it, throw an error like this. 
`uri = https://system/posts/videos/000/000/001/original/VID_20160123_201801.mp4?1453620267
01-24 17:22:51.108 32752-32752/com.user.franklyspeak D/MediaPlayer_Java: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
01-24 17:22:51.138 32752-32752/com.user.franklyspeak E/MediaPlayer-JNI: [FXN][ASD]getVideoSurfaceTexture: null surface texture
01-24 17:22:51.399 32752-32763/com.user.franklyspeak E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
01-24 17:22:51.399 32752-32752/com.user.franklyspeak E/MediaPlayer_Java: Error (1,-1004)
01-24 17:22:51.399 32752-32752/com.user.franklyspeak D/VideoView: Error: 1,-1004`

My controller code looks like this

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    render json: @posts
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    p = @post.video.url
    render json: @post.video.url
    # render json: @post
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :video)
    end
end
```

My model looks like this.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :video

    do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :video

    # validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: are you using any video processors like paperclip-ffmpeg or something

Comment: @bijendra I added the gem but still the error remains the same.